# Subclassed QWebView doesn't react to Hyperlink Clicks

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

This is in Python/PySide.

I am trying to create my own Parental WebBrowser by overloading the PySide.QtWebKit.QWebView widget. Then whenever someone clicks a link on the widget I check to see if we are going to an invalid website, if not we proceed, if yes then I redirect to a generic page.

**So I have subclassed the PySide.QtWebKit.QWebView, but I am not receiving notification of when a link is clicked. I have overridden the linkClicked function but the function never runs when a link is clicked?**

What am I doing wrong? Why cant my function run/react to the hyperlink click "event"? Do I need to override the webpage object & not this class to react to link clicks?

```
import PySide.QtWebKit
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class BrowserWindow( PySide.QtWebKit.QWebView ):
    # Class Variables:

    def __init__( self, _parent ):
        """ Constructor: """

        super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__()
        PySide.QtWebKit.QWebView(None)


    def linkClicked(self, arg__1):
        """ Post: """

        #print("LINK CLICKED")
        #text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 
        #    'Enter your name:')

        self.load("http://yahoo.com")


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = BrowserWindow(None) #PySide.QtWebKit.QWebView(None)
    view.load("http://google.com")
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you posted. Firstly, you are importing both PySide and PyQt4, which is not a good idea. Secondly, `QWebView.linkClicked` is a signal, not a protected method, so you can't override it. Thirdly, you are passing a string to `QWebView.load`, when you should be passing a `QtCore.QUrl`.

However, aside from those problems, you also need to set the [linkDelegationPolicy](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtWebKit/QWebPage.html#PySide.QtWebKit.PySide.QtWebKit.QWebPage.linkDelegationPolicy) on the web page in order to override its link handling.

Here's an edited version of your code which should fix all the problems:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class BrowserWindow(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__()
        self.linkClicked.connect(self.handleLinkClicked)

    def handleLinkClicked(self, url):
        print(url.toString())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = BrowserWindow()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://google.com"))
    view.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```